# How can I get a list of VMS not connected to a Log Analytics Worspace?

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to list VMS not connected to an azure Log Analytics workspace. Whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: Please put in a bit more effort to enable us to help you. Add information like what you tried and what didn't work. Please refer to [ask]. In it's current form, this question is not a fit for SO.

Comment: Run one query against Log Analytics `$LogAnlyticsVMs = "Select distinct computername"`.  Then run `$azureVMs = Get-AzVm | select -unique hostname`.  Then filter

Comment: that gives me an error "Query could not be parsed at '=' on line [1,16]"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly from the portal on the Log Analytics Workspace

- Go to your LA Workspace
- Click Agents Management

[image]

- Click Go to logs

This will give you each machine which is checking in to that workspace.

```
Heartbeat
| where OSType == 'Windows'
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by SourceComputerId
| sort by Computer
```

You can customise that query to include linux OS' too if you so desire.

If you need to run this from PowerShell you can run the same query with `Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery`

The docs on how to do that are here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/invoke-azoperationalinsightsquery?view=azps-6.3.0